# Why doesn't my form's OnKeyDown event handler fire?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, keyboard-events

I'm using Delphi 2009 and I followed [a tutorial at delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/humorandfun/a/delphieasteregg.htm), but I couldn't set it.

I created an event OnKeyPress/OnkeyDown and set a breakpoint to see if the event is called, but it's not being called in any way.

Where is the problem?

**EDIT**:

```
procedure TFormMain.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Beep; //breakpoint is set here.
end;
```

Comment: Beep; That's the code.And there is a breakpoint on it,but it never reaches that breakpoint.

Comment: do you want us to tell you how big your feet are too? :)

Comment: Could you link to the tutorial or give some more details in andy way? "But i couldn't set it" - what's that supposed to mean?

Comment: No need for now.I thought,maybe there is something else to set if that event is never fired up.Is there?

Comment: Smasher, http://delphi.about.com/od/humorandfun/a/delphieasteregg.htm

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might try to set

```
Form1.KeyPreview := True;
```

Maybe the event is not properly delegated up to the form.

**EDIT:** after looking at the link I guess you probably have done that since it is mentioned in the article. Maybe you forgot that line?

Comment: @John: You can set it in the Object Inspector, too, and then you don't need to remember to type it.